# How to create a simple sticky navigation element to the side of content?

Tags: html, css, sticky

In the following example I am trying to create a layout where the navigation will:

1. Always stay sticky to the top when scrolling down
2. Always stay left (not all the way left of the browser window) from content which a person is able to read
3. Prevent any space from being taken up by the actual navigation element's size

```css
header h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  display: block;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: orange;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-container">
  <header>
    <h1>
      Some header
    </h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#below">Below</a></li>
      <li><a href="#above">Above</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <h1>
      Below is some content
    </h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nunc nisl, cursus quis nisi id, iaculis auctor ex. Donec dapibus ultricies fringilla. Phasellus posuere lobortis orci, ut bibendum nibh varius a. Etiam ut dignissim lacus, ut iaculis mi.
      Donec cursus semper libero. Vivamus tincidunt magna a orci porta, eget faucibus tellus pharetra. Pellentesque dapibus tincidunt ligula et venenatis. Nunc ullamcorper purus ac neque sagittis, et molestie purus sodales. Vestibulum ornare ac nisl ut
      dignissim. Vestibulum nec maximus neque. Ut euismod, velit quis pharetra venenatis, lectus metus porttitor sapien, id bibendum nisi ex ac odio. Aenean quis diam sed metus posuere pellentesque. Quisque tellus quam, suscipit non enim et, pellentesque
      varius magna. Quisque euismod massa vitae ex blandit interdum. Aliquam fermentum congue eros elementum rutrum. Donec sit amet nunc a mi tincidunt pulvinar accumsan a purus.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tempus turpis a libero fermentum, nec commodo dolor interdum. Proin fringilla finibus hendrerit. Phasellus rutrum lectus sit amet metus pellentesque accumsan. Duis maximus augue id lacus
      tempus interdum. Maecenas ut convallis nisi. Cras porta risus at massa vehicula semper. Nunc odio justo, porttitor at faucibus ut, sodales id erat.
    </p>
    <p>
      Integer fermentum ut felis a luctus. Suspendisse enim elit, finibus at erat sit amet, ultrices rutrum velit. Proin eget mi et massa porttitor tincidunt a tempus ipsum. Pellentesque maximus pharetra lectus nec cursus. Nullam ut arcu lacus. Vivamus eleifend
      ultrices diam nec hendrerit. Ut et malesuada urna, id luctus risus.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vestibulum accumsan sed libero at rutrum. In id tristique magna, id faucibus quam. Quisque nisi est, iaculis ut interdum at, varius et quam. Proin tempus nunc id libero viverra interdum. Vivamus id risus tortor. Fusce in laoreet lacus. Cras dui sapien,
      convallis sed turpis eu, porttitor luctus justo. Praesent mi augue, sodales in cursus ut, pulvinar eget ex.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vestibulum ex urna, viverra vel risus ultricies, facilisis vulputate velit. Nullam semper urna diam, pulvinar imperdiet tortor egestas fermentum. Ut volutpat, mi at aliquet porta, metus augue tempus ex, at euismod orci felis sit amet neque. Maecenas fringilla
      enim ac accumsan vestibulum. Suspendisse pellentesque consectetur urna. Maecenas laoreet fringilla leo vitae ultrices. Aenean sodales auctor nibh et eleifend. Donec semper facilisis mauris vel fringilla. Integer imperdiet massa eu orci faucibus
      mattis.
    </p>
    <h1 id="above">Above all</h1>
  </main>
</div>
```

I tried using the `right` property (on the `nav` selector) to see if I could use it to make it stick to the container with the actual content inside but it does not do anything at all. Most webpages I could find with a navigation to the sides tend to touch the browsers sides and this is not the solution I am looking for, which makes it difficult for me to find a solution to this problem.

What I intend to make the page look like:

[image: Intention]

Comment: you can create a sticky element. [read here.](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp)

Comment: I was already using a sticky element (refer to the code in my question). @DhruviMakvana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution. I wrapped `nav` and `main` in an extra container, giving it the class name `some-container-inside`. In css, I changed all my edits. Hope this is what you need.

```css
header h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  display: block;
  max-width: 500px;
  /*margin-left: auto;*/  /*delete this it*/
  /*margin-right: auto;*/ /*delete this it*/
  width: 100%;
}

main h1 {
  margin-top: 0; /*add this it*/
}

nav {
  display: table; /*add this it*/
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-right: 25px; /*add this it*/
  margin-left: 25px; /*add this it*/
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.some-container-inside {
  display: flex; /*add this it*/
  justify-content: center; /*add this it*/
}
```

```html
<div class="some-container">
  <header>
    <h1>
      Some header
    </h1>
  </header>
  <div class="some-container-inside">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#below">Below</a></li>
      <li><a href="#above">Above</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <h1>
      Below is some content
    </h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nunc nisl, cursus quis nisi id, iaculis auctor ex. Donec dapibus ultricies fringilla. Phasellus posuere lobortis orci, ut bibendum nibh varius a. Etiam ut dignissim lacus, ut iaculis mi.
      Donec cursus semper libero. Vivamus tincidunt magna a orci porta, eget faucibus tellus pharetra. Pellentesque dapibus tincidunt ligula et venenatis. Nunc ullamcorper purus ac neque sagittis, et molestie purus sodales. Vestibulum ornare ac nisl ut
      dignissim. Vestibulum nec maximus neque. Ut euismod, velit quis pharetra venenatis, lectus metus porttitor sapien, id bibendum nisi ex ac odio. Aenean quis diam sed metus posuere pellentesque. Quisque tellus quam, suscipit non enim et, pellentesque
      varius magna. Quisque euismod massa vitae ex blandit interdum. Aliquam fermentum congue eros elementum rutrum. Donec sit amet nunc a mi tincidunt pulvinar accumsan a purus.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tempus turpis a libero fermentum, nec commodo dolor interdum. Proin fringilla finibus hendrerit. Phasellus rutrum lectus sit amet metus pellentesque accumsan. Duis maximus augue id lacus
      tempus interdum. Maecenas ut convallis nisi. Cras porta risus at massa vehicula semper. Nunc odio justo, porttitor at faucibus ut, sodales id erat.
    </p>
    <p>
      Integer fermentum ut felis a luctus. Suspendisse enim elit, finibus at erat sit amet, ultrices rutrum velit. Proin eget mi et massa porttitor tincidunt a tempus ipsum. Pellentesque maximus pharetra lectus nec cursus. Nullam ut arcu lacus. Vivamus eleifend
      ultrices diam nec hendrerit. Ut et malesuada urna, id luctus risus.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vestibulum accumsan sed libero at rutrum. In id tristique magna, id faucibus quam. Quisque nisi est, iaculis ut interdum at, varius et quam. Proin tempus nunc id libero viverra interdum. Vivamus id risus tortor. Fusce in laoreet lacus. Cras dui sapien,
      convallis sed turpis eu, porttitor luctus justo. Praesent mi augue, sodales in cursus ut, pulvinar eget ex.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vestibulum ex urna, viverra vel risus ultricies, facilisis vulputate velit. Nullam semper urna diam, pulvinar imperdiet tortor egestas fermentum. Ut volutpat, mi at aliquet porta, metus augue tempus ex, at euismod orci felis sit amet neque. Maecenas fringilla
      enim ac accumsan vestibulum. Suspendisse pellentesque consectetur urna. Maecenas laoreet fringilla leo vitae ultrices. Aenean sodales auctor nibh et eleifend. Donec semper facilisis mauris vel fringilla. Integer imperdiet massa eu orci faucibus
      mattis.
    </p>
    <h1 id="above">Above all</h1>
  </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for although setting the `display` property of the `nav` element to a value of `table`, won't it add unintended behaviour? I mean to have read something about not using tables to style web pages and all. I tried using `align-self: flex-start` instead. Great solution nonetheless.

Comment: @Barrosy, A table display is normal practice. Yes, I also tried `align-self: flex-start`, and everything works well, but the `tables` have good `cross-browser` compatibility. Thanks, and I was glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

### Version 1: HTML / CSS

The changes I made in:

**HTML:** The `NAV` element is in the `MAIN` element

**CSS:** On the `NAV` element set style `margin-left: -230px;` and `margin-bottom: -130px;`

---

*In this version, if you add a new menu item, you must manually set the `margin-bottom:`*

**If you want this to be done automatically see Version 2 below in this post**

```css
header h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

main {
    display: block;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

nav {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -230px;
    margin-bottom: -130px;
    background-color: orange;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul a {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-container">
    <header>
        <h1>
            Some header
        </h1>
    </header>

    <main>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#below">Below</a></li>
                <li><a href="#above">Above</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <h1>
            Below is some content
        </h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nunc nisl, cursus quis nisi id, iaculis
            auctor ex. Donec dapibus ultricies fringilla. Phasellus posuere lobortis orci, ut bibendum nibh varius
            a. Etiam ut dignissim lacus, ut iaculis mi.
            Donec cursus semper libero. Vivamus tincidunt magna a orci porta, eget faucibus tellus pharetra.
            Pellentesque dapibus tincidunt ligula et venenatis. Nunc ullamcorper purus ac neque sagittis, et
            molestie purus sodales. Vestibulum ornare ac nisl ut
            dignissim. Vestibulum nec maximus neque. Ut euismod, velit quis pharetra venenatis, lectus metus
            porttitor sapien, id bibendum nisi ex ac odio. Aenean quis diam sed metus posuere pellentesque. Quisque
            tellus quam, suscipit non enim et, pellentesque
            varius magna. Quisque euismod massa vitae ex blandit interdum. Aliquam fermentum congue eros elementum
            rutrum. Donec sit amet nunc a mi tincidunt pulvinar accumsan a purus.
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tempus turpis a libero fermentum,
            nec commodo dolor interdum. Proin fringilla finibus hendrerit. Phasellus rutrum lectus sit amet metus
            pellentesque accumsan. Duis maximus augue id lacus
            tempus interdum. Maecenas ut convallis nisi. Cras porta risus at massa vehicula semper. Nunc odio justo,
            porttitor at faucibus ut, sodales id erat.
        </p>
        <p>
            Integer fermentum ut felis a luctus. Suspendisse enim elit, finibus at erat sit amet, ultrices rutrum
            velit. Proin eget mi et massa porttitor tincidunt a tempus ipsum. Pellentesque maximus pharetra lectus
            nec cursus. Nullam ut arcu lacus. Vivamus eleifend
            ultrices diam nec hendrerit. Ut et malesuada urna, id luctus risus.
        </p>
        <p>
            Vestibulum accumsan sed libero at rutrum. In id tristique magna, id faucibus quam. Quisque nisi est,
            iaculis ut interdum at, varius et quam. Proin tempus nunc id libero viverra interdum. Vivamus id risus
            tortor. Fusce in laoreet lacus. Cras dui sapien,
            convallis sed turpis eu, porttitor luctus justo. Praesent mi augue, sodales in cursus ut, pulvinar eget
            ex.
        </p>
        <p>
            Vestibulum ex urna, viverra vel risus ultricies, facilisis vulputate velit. Nullam semper urna diam,
            pulvinar imperdiet tortor egestas fermentum. Ut volutpat, mi at aliquet porta, metus augue tempus ex, at
            euismod orci felis sit amet neque. Maecenas fringilla
            enim ac accumsan vestibulum. Suspendisse pellentesque consectetur urna. Maecenas laoreet fringilla leo
            vitae ultrices. Aenean sodales auctor nibh et eleifend. Donec semper facilisis mauris vel fringilla.
            Integer imperdiet massa eu orci faucibus
            mattis.
        </p>
        <h1 id="above">Above all</h1>
    </main>
</div>
```

---

### Version 2: HTML / CSS / JS

You can add new items to the navigation and the JS will make the necessary changes so that the navigation is always displayed in the right place.

*Important: The JS code must be added at the bottom of the page code*

```js
var nav = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0];
nav.setAttribute('style', 'margin-bottom:-' + (nav.offsetHeight + 30) + 'px');
```

```css
header h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

main {
    display: block;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

nav {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -230px;
    background-color: orange;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul a {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-container">
    <header>
        <h1>
            Some header
        </h1>
    </header>

    <main>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#below">Below</a></li>
                <li><a href="#above">Above</a></li>
                <li><a href="#above">Contacts</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <h1>
            Below is some content
        </h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nunc nisl, cursus quis nisi id, iaculis
            auctor ex. Donec dapibus ultricies fringilla. Phasellus posuere lobortis orci, ut bibendum nibh varius
            a. Etiam ut dignissim lacus, ut iaculis mi.
            Donec cursus semper libero. Vivamus tincidunt magna a orci porta, eget faucibus tellus pharetra.
            Pellentesque dapibus tincidunt ligula et venenatis. Nunc ullamcorper purus ac neque sagittis, et
            molestie purus sodales. Vestibulum ornare ac nisl ut
            dignissim. Vestibulum nec maximus neque. Ut euismod, velit quis pharetra venenatis, lectus metus
            porttitor sapien, id bibendum nisi ex ac odio. Aenean quis diam sed metus posuere pellentesque. Quisque
            tellus quam, suscipit non enim et, pellentesque
            varius magna. Quisque euismod massa vitae ex blandit interdum. Aliquam fermentum congue eros elementum
            rutrum. Donec sit amet nunc a mi tincidunt pulvinar accumsan a purus.
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tempus turpis a libero fermentum,
            nec commodo dolor interdum. Proin fringilla finibus hendrerit. Phasellus rutrum lectus sit amet metus
            pellentesque accumsan. Duis maximus augue id lacus
            tempus interdum. Maecenas ut convallis nisi. Cras porta risus at massa vehicula semper. Nunc odio justo,
            porttitor at faucibus ut, sodales id erat.
        </p>
        <p>
            Integer fermentum ut felis a luctus. Suspendisse enim elit, finibus at erat sit amet, ultrices rutrum
            velit. Proin eget mi et massa porttitor tincidunt a tempus ipsum. Pellentesque maximus pharetra lectus
            nec cursus. Nullam ut arcu lacus. Vivamus eleifend
            ultrices diam nec hendrerit. Ut et malesuada urna, id luctus risus.
        </p>
        <p>
            Vestibulum accumsan sed libero at rutrum. In id tristique magna, id faucibus quam. Quisque nisi est,
            iaculis ut interdum at, varius et quam. Proin tempus nunc id libero viverra interdum. Vivamus id risus
            tortor. Fusce in laoreet lacus. Cras dui sapien,
            convallis sed turpis eu, porttitor luctus justo. Praesent mi augue, sodales in cursus ut, pulvinar eget
            ex.
        </p>
        <p>
            Vestibulum ex urna, viverra vel risus ultricies, facilisis vulputate velit. Nullam semper urna diam,
            pulvinar imperdiet tortor egestas fermentum. Ut volutpat, mi at aliquet porta, metus augue tempus ex, at
            euismod orci felis sit amet neque. Maecenas fringilla
            enim ac accumsan vestibulum. Suspendisse pellentesque consectetur urna. Maecenas laoreet fringilla leo
            vitae ultrices. Aenean sodales auctor nibh et eleifend. Donec semper facilisis mauris vel fringilla.
            Integer imperdiet massa eu orci faucibus
            mattis.
        </p>
        <h1 id="above">Above all</h1>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with this solution other than that using JavaScript seems kind of like overkill for the purpose of my question.

Comment: Of course! So I made two options so you can decide which one would be more useful to you

Answer (score 0):

This code you try .

hope can help  you.

i add position property on some class tag.

ex:header h1,nav . and new class some-container.

```css
header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 850px;
  top: 50px;
}

main {
  display: block;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 135px;
  left: 480px;
  background-color: orange;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.some-container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-container">
  <header>
    <h1>
      Some header
    </h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#below">Below</a></li>
      <li><a href="#above">Above</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <h1>
      Below is some content
    </h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque nunc nisl, cursus quis nisi id, iaculis auctor ex. Donec dapibus ultricies fringilla. Phasellus posuere lobortis orci, ut bibendum nibh varius a. Etiam ut dignissim lacus, ut iaculis mi.
      Donec cursus semper libero. Vivamus tincidunt magna a orci porta, eget faucibus tellus pharetra. Pellentesque dapibus tincidunt ligula et venenatis. Nunc ullamcorper purus ac neque sagittis, et molestie purus sodales. Vestibulum ornare ac nisl ut
      dignissim. Vestibulum nec maximus neque. Ut euismod, velit quis pharetra venenatis, lectus metus porttitor sapien, id bibendum nisi ex ac odio. Aenean quis diam sed metus posuere pellentesque. Quisque tellus quam, suscipit non enim et, pellentesque
      varius magna. Quisque euismod massa vitae ex blandit interdum. Aliquam fermentum congue eros elementum rutrum. Donec sit amet nunc a mi tincidunt pulvinar accumsan a purus.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse tempus turpis a libero fermentum, nec commodo dolor interdum. Proin fringilla finibus hendrerit. Phasellus rutrum lectus sit amet metus pellentesque accumsan. Duis maximus augue id lacus
      tempus interdum. Maecenas ut convallis nisi. Cras porta risus at massa vehicula semper. Nunc odio justo, porttitor at faucibus ut, sodales id erat.
    </p>
    <p>
      Integer fermentum ut felis a luctus. Suspendisse enim elit, finibus at erat sit amet, ultrices rutrum velit. Proin eget mi et massa porttitor tincidunt a tempus ipsum. Pellentesque maximus pharetra lectus nec cursus. Nullam ut arcu lacus. Vivamus eleifend
      ultrices diam nec hendrerit. Ut et malesuada urna, id luctus risus.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vestibulum accumsan sed libero at rutrum. In id tristique magna, id faucibus quam. Quisque nisi est, iaculis ut interdum at, varius et quam. Proin tempus nunc id libero viverra interdum. Vivamus id risus tortor. Fusce in laoreet lacus. Cras dui sapien,
      convallis sed turpis eu, porttitor luctus justo. Praesent mi augue, sodales in cursus ut, pulvinar eget ex.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vestibulum ex urna, viverra vel risus ultricies, facilisis vulputate velit. Nullam semper urna diam, pulvinar imperdiet tortor egestas fermentum. Ut volutpat, mi at aliquet porta, metus augue tempus ex, at euismod orci felis sit amet neque. Maecenas fringilla
      enim ac accumsan vestibulum. Suspendisse pellentesque consectetur urna. Maecenas laoreet fringilla leo vitae ultrices. Aenean sodales auctor nibh et eleifend. Donec semper facilisis mauris vel fringilla. Integer imperdiet massa eu orci faucibus
      mattis.
    </p>
    <h1 id="above">Above all</h1>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Lets say it has to be a responsive webpage, the `nav` element won't stay in the same position I considered in my question when scaling the window (I know I didn't mention repsonsiveness but previous mentioned answer offered a better solution).